# Remove blank lines in StringBuffer

Tags: java, string, split, filereader, stringbuffer

After reading text file that contain words and numbers, I split it into words and numbers and left with blank lines in both splited words and numbers.

I try to remove the blank lines but the code did'nt work. Someone can help

```
 String textfile = read.next();

 String[] words = textfile.split("\\d");
 String[] numbers = textfile.split("[^0-9]");

 StringBuffer splitedwords = new  StringBuffer();

 StringBuffer splitednumbers = new StringBuffer();

  for(int k = 0; k<numbers.length; k++ )

  {

    splitednumbers.append(numbers[k]);

 String remove_blank_lines_of_splitednumbers = splitednumbers.toString();


   remove_blank_lines_of_splitednumbers.replaceAll("[\r\n]{2,}",  "");

 System.out.println(remove_blank_lines_of_splitednumbers);

  }
```

Igot this output

```
13
46
16

   

   


 08
 96
 11






 150
 200
 379
```

I want the output to be

```
 13
 46 
 16
  08
  96
  11
  150
  200
  379
```

Comment: I think you are not capturing the result of `remove_blank_lines_of_splitednumbers.replaceAll("[\r\n]{2,}",  "");` back in `remove_blank_lines_of_splitednumbers` Try writing `System.out.println(remove_blank_lines_of_splitednumbers.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]{2,}",  ""));` or ``System.out.println(remove_blank_lines_of_splitednumbers.replaceAll("\\R{2,}",  ""));`` with doubled backslashes.

Comment: it does'nt work

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove white spaces, such as your empty lines, at the beginning or end of a String you can simply use the trim method instead of restorting to a replace with a regex.

If you'll aplly a trim on each numbers[k] in your for you should be able to remove every white characters around them.

```
splitednumbers.append(numbers[k].trim());
```

Or try still the replaceAll withe a regex matching white spaces.

```
splitednumbers.append(numbers[k].replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
```

Comment: it does'nt work

Comment: @NajibuTanimu I've edited the answer with also a replaceAll approach

Comment: thank you but does'nt yield required output

Comment: what I exprience is that, the String array words and Numbers contain index with empty element, may be if you can asist with code to remove the index with empty elements it will work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should still try with a replaceAll but using the \s character class though. I don't think this code (replaceAll("[\r\n]{2,}",  ""); can detect you new lines and carriage return the way you expect.

Comment: thank you but I dont know why it does'nt work